# AJAX request not working while working on POSTMAN

Tags: php, json, ajax, postman

I'm quite new with API and AJAX and I'm encountering an issue here. I have created an endpoint in PHP (Symfony).

When I call a GET on this endpoint with Postman, I'm getting the answer correctly.

[image]

But I get a 500 error when I try to get the answer with AJAX.
Here my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <button id="testButton">TEST</button>
    <script>
        $('#testButton').click(function (e) {

            let week = 42;
            let year = 2021;
            let data = JSON.stringify({
                id:1,
                week: week,
                year: year}
            );
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ path('bookings')}}',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(status)
                    if (status === 'success') {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log('success');
                    } else {
                        console.log('failure');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Path(bookings) returns 127.0.0.1:8000/bookings.

Here the error I get:
[image]

Could you please indicate me where I'm making a mistake, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a GET request using jQuery you can pass `data` property as a `PlainObject`

try this out without stringify:

```
let data = {
   id:1,
   week: week,
   year: year
};
```